# VBA conversion liter to gallon

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me?
I'm now making a useform and some calculations through excel vba.
I want to input a value into a textbox and to convert this to the corresponding unit in another text box instantly without any button.

E.g. flow rate in LPM(Liter per minute ): I want to convert it into gallon per minute .

```
1LPM=0.2641
```

If I type `10LPM`, I'd like the result in the second box to be `=10*0.2641`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.Value * 0.2641
    Else
        TextBox2.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code sir i have some more dobuts @love coding